Sony WF-C700N earbuds does not detect microphone (Windows 11)
I have rebooted and re-added my earbuds. The audio out is fine. No microphone is detected.
Sony community forums has a redirect loop on login and holds no clues.
I have enabled display disabled devices but the mic does not show
The earbuds are a few months old and function correctly on my phone
[Update: screen shots]


Any clues?

You need to select the HFP ("Hands Free") (mono + mic) instead of the default A2DP (HiFi Stereo, no mic).

There are no such options in the Sound control panel
